# Number of parameters for conditional probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let's assume we have P(A|B) with A and B beeing two binary random variables. Why do we only need 2 parameters to specify the distribution? Namely P(A=true | B = true) and P(A = true | B = false).

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a very well posed question.  We "only need 2 parameters" to answer what question?  If the question to be asked involves **only** A and B then those are the only two parameters we need.  But we might have a question in which we have P(A|B) but there are also other parameters.

Comment: @user247327 I mean the amount of values needed to specify P(A|B) which can be P(A = true) | B = true), P(A = true | B = false), P(A = false | B = true), P(A = false | B = false). So we have 4 values but we only need two values and can infer the other two values. But how?